# URL dispatcher: how to pass a variable with differnt length

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I want to pass a variable from the requested url to a view. With a predefined variable-length or just ja number it woudn't be a problem, but now my variable to pass can differ in length.

I want something like this

```
url(r'^test/(?P<my_var>\d+)/$', views.Vote),
```

but `my_var` should be able to be for example `hello`, `blablabla` or `where_am_i_going`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL patters are regular expressions, so just use one that captures values you expect. From  your description it sounds like you want to match one or more alphanumeric characters or underscores. In that case the pattern would look like this:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<my_var>\w+)/$', views.Vote),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<my_var>\w+)/$', views.Vote),
```